# Found a good ticker on JQuery but how do I make it loop infinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ticker

I added in a ticker my teacher recommended me from jQuery and it works great but when the text is done, it doesn't loop immediately. The text stops coming from the right, just goes of the screen on the left and when it's completely gone the whole thing starts over. I was hoping someone knows what I have to add/change to the code to make it loop directly when the first round of text in done.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.newsTicker = function(options) {
        if($(this).length < 1) return this;

        var opt = $.extend(true,{
            base : {
                width : 2100,
                time : 40000
            },
            itemWidth : "auto",
            ticker : ".ti_news",
            tickerClone : "ti_clone",
            wrapper : ".ti_wrapper",
            slide : ".ti_slide",
            content : ".ti_content",

            callbacks : {
                beforeLoad : function($Ticker){},
                onLoad : function($current,$Ticker){},
                beforeAnimation : function($old,$current){},
                completeAnimation : function($old,$current){},
                isPaused : function($current,$Ticker){},
                isResumed : function($current,$Ticker){}
            },

            core : {
                _getTime : function(w){
                    baseMargin=(typeof $contentTickers === "undefined") ? 0 : $contentTickers.first().css("margin-left");
                    baseMargin=(baseMargin<0)?baseMargin:0;
                    return opt.base.time * (w / (baseMargin + opt.base.width));
                },

                _contentWidth : function($tickers){
                    var w = 0;
                    if(opt.itemWidth !== "auto" && opt.itemWidth !== 0){
                        w = $tickers.length * opt.itemWidth;
                        $tickers.width(opt.itemWidth);
                    }else{
                        $tickers.each(function(){w = w + $(this).width()});
                    }
                    return Math.ceil(w+2);
                }
            }

        },options); 

        $(this).each(function(){
            var $Ticker = $(this);

                $Ticker.data("ticker",{
                    stop:true,
                    animation:null
                });

            opt.callbacks.beforeLoad($(this));

            var $notizieTicker = $Ticker.find(opt.ticker),
            $wrapperTicker = $Ticker.find(opt.wrapper),
            $ti_slide = $Ticker.find(opt.slide),
            $contentTicker = $Ticker.find(opt.content);

            var width_content = opt.core._contentWidth($notizieTicker),
                wrapper_width = $wrapperTicker.width(),
                $current,
                $old = $();

            if(width_content < wrapper_width){
                var x = Math.ceil(wrapper_width/width_content),
                    $clone = $contentTicker.children().clone();
                for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                    $contentTicker.append($clone.clone());
                }
                if(!opt.itemWidth || opt.itemWidth == "auto"){
                    width_content = width_content*i;
                }else{
                    width_content = ($contentTicker.children().length * opt.itemWidth);
                }
            }

            if(width_content * 3 > $ti_slide.width()) $ti_slide.width((width_content*3)+100);

            $ti_slide.append($contentTicker.clone().addClass(opt.tickerClone));
            $ti_slide.append($contentTicker.clone().addClass(opt.tickerClone));

            var $contentTickers = $Ticker.find(opt.content);
                $contentTickers.width(width_content);

            $current = $contentTickers.first();

            opt.callbacks.onLoad($current,$(this));

            var animateTicker = function(m){
                $ti_slide.append($old);
                var m = (typeof m == "undefined") ? 0 : m ; 
                $old.css("margin-left",m);

                opt.callbacks.beforeAnimation($old,$current);

                $Ticker.data("stop",false);
                var tickerAnimation = $current.animate({
                    "margin-left" : -width_content,
                },{
                    easing : "linear",
                    duration : opt.core._getTime(width_content),
                    complete : function(){
                        $old = $current;
                        $current = $current.next();
                        opt.callbacks.completeAnimation($old,$current);
                        animateTicker.call($Ticker);
                    }
                });
                $Ticker.data("animation",tickerAnimation);
            }

            animateTicker.call(this);

            $Ticker[0].pauseTicker = function(){
                $Ticker.each(function(){
                    var _anim = $Ticker.data("animation"),
                        _stop = $Ticker.data("stop");
                    if(!!_stop || !_anim) return;
                    _anim.stop();
                    $Ticker.data("stop",true);
                    opt.callbacks.isPaused();
                });
            }

            $Ticker[0].startTicker = function(){
                $Ticker.each(function(){
                    if(!$Ticker.data("stop")) return;
                    animateTicker($Ticker);
                    $Ticker.data("stop",false);
                    opt.callbacks.isResumed();
                });
            }
        });

        return this;
    };

    $.fn.newsTickerPause = function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            if("pauseTicker" in $(this)[0]) $(this)[0].pauseTicker();
        });
    }

    $.fn.newsTickerResume = function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            if("startTicker" in $(this)[0]) $(this)[0].startTicker();
        });
    }

}( jQuery ));
```

```css
.TickerNews {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.ti_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

.ti_slide {
  width: 30000px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.ti_content {
  width: 8000px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.ti_news { float: left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="upcoming">
  <div class="TickerNews" id="T3">
      <div class="ti_wrapper">
          <div class="ti_slide">
              <div class="ti_content">
                  <div class="ti_news">
            text
          </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                _Ticker = $(".TickerNews").newsTicker();
                
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the library you're using? It seems something is amiss in your example for us to re-produce your case.

Comment: @Dominik i added what i think is the library? i'm sorry i don't really know much of the coding jargon yet :/

Comment: No worries, we all started from the beginning at some point. In this case you added meta tags. Those won't help us. Look for the javaScript file that contains the library. You can see when you click the `Run code snippet` button that nothing is moving.

Comment: @Dominik i see! i'm going to try to add more from my original document to see if it works

Comment: @Dominik for some reason i can't make the preview work, sorry :/ I think it's because i can't add the first Jquery link? not sure. It's supposed to be this ticker https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-News-Ticker-Plugin-with-jQuery-tickerNews/

Comment: works now does it?

Comment: @Dominik yes! thanks!!